# stretch background image set to hr tag

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a webpage where I have `hr` tags to separate sections in page.

I am applying an image as background to hr tag using css.

The hr tag takes 100% width but image does not occupy entire tag.

How to force image to occupy the entire area occupied by `hr` tag?

Is there any stretching property available to stretch image end-to-end?

Below is the code:

```
hr
{

    background: url("images/new/edge-top.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    color: transparent;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    clear: both;
    border: 0 none;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px;

}
```

Check the resulting image here:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS3 has some new options for that. Try

```
background-size: x% x%;
```

Here you can read **[the Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-background-20020802/#background-size)** for the new background-module.

Note however, that this is very poorly [supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-s)  in IE! (anyone surprised?)